# Can't set percentage height of an element whose parent element has a min-height set to 100%

Tags: html, css

So I did  a little research, and it turns out this issue has been addressed a few times. You cannot set a height in percentages if the parent element has a min-height set to a percentage value as well, which sounds kind of logical.

The answer to this problem would be to set the parent element to a fixed amount of pixels. However, this is kind of a problem for me since I want the page to have a percentage value set as height.

I have a header and body element which are stacked in a parent element, so that I can give the parent element a box-shadow. That way the shadows won't overlap and look weird. So my solution would be to not at all set the height of the parent element so it would be variable, but that way I can't set the child element to a percentage since, well, the parent element height is not set.

For this all to make a little more sense, here is the HTML and CSS:

[HTML]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/animateheader.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content_parent">
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header_parent">

            </div>

            <!-- Body (homepage) -->
            <div id="body_parent">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer_parent">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

[CSS]

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

* {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#content_parent {
    min-height:100%;
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px rgb(100,100,100);
}

#header_parent {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
    box-shadow:-6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 6px 4px -2px rgb(100,100,100);
    -webkit-box-shadow:-6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 6px 4px -2px rgb(100,100,100);
    -moz-box-shadow:-6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 6px 4px -2px rgb(100,100,100);
    border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:0;
}

#body_parent {
    height:100%;
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    background-color:rgb(245,245,245);
}
```

Also, here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c1koxsc/).

Just to be clear, I run into problems when setting the height of `#body_parent` and the parent element is `#content_parent`

Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add following css

#content_parent {
    min-height:100%;
    max-width:1250px;
    min-width:750px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px rgb(100, 100, 100);
    height:100%; /* add this */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0c1koxsc/1/)

Edit after comment

remove `height: 100%` from `body, html{}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0c1koxsc/3/)

Comment: But will the height still be dynamic? I mean if I were to add content to the #body_parent element would the #content_parent's height still change if the content would go further than 100%? Thanks for your effort though :)

Comment: Yes, because you wanted it to have a min-height of 100%, I just added a height 100% to it for reasons stated in your problem statement.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c1koxsc/2/) I tried adding some professional content to it, but it doesn't seem to expand. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: checkout edit in answer, the issues was because of specified height of html, body to be 100%

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem :) Didn't expect it to be this easy.